# Xcode 8 add Capabilities from terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, bash

Have I ability to enable in capabilities Push Notification from bash?
My problem that my builds are using CI.
If I build debug builds with provision, that has app bundle with wildcard *
And I will enable push notification in capabilities **debug** build will not compile. Because wildcard provision not support Push Notifications

But I need it for **release** build with normal provision. In this case I need enable push notification in capabilities.
I want to enable it with script if it is real, only for release.

If someone know another approach will be glad to hear.
Will be appreciated for any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Script I wrote to enable Push Notifications in a Cordova project.

You'll need to modify it to set the DevelopmentTeam to the correct value.

hooks/before_compile/capabilities.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# Abort on Error
set -e

APP_NAME=$(sed -e 's/xmlns.*/>/g' config.xml | xmllint --xpath '/widget/name/text()' -)
PROJECT=`find platforms/ios/${APP_NAME} -name project.pbxproj`

# Exit if not required
grep 'TargetAttributes' ${PROJECT} > /dev/null && exit

# Backup
set -x
cp ${PROJECT} ${PROJECT}.orig

# Get ID
ID=`grep -A 1 'Begin PBXNativeTarget section' ${PROJECT} | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tr -d '\t'`

# Inject
sed -i '' -e "/LastUpgradeCheck.*$/a\\
TargetAttributes = {\\
${ID} = {\\
DevelopmentTeam = ABCD1234YZ;\\
SystemCapabilities = {\\
com.apple.Push = {\\
enabled = 1;\\
};\\
};\\
};\\
};" ${PROJECT}

# Compare
diff ${PROJECT}.orig ${PROJECT}
```